# how to access protected property response from facebook in facebook ads api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, codeigniter-3, facebook-ads-api

I am getting a protected object returned from the API call to Facebook Ads.

```
 $page = new Page($page_id);
 $leadgen_forms = $page->getLeadgenForms();
```

I am getting the response like this :

```
    FacebookAds\Object\Page
          (
      [response:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Response Object
         (
            [response:protected] => Array
              (
                   [data] => Array
                        (
                             MY DATA
                        )
              )
    )
  )
```

I have already used used [Reflection](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiAwYXmwozQAhVLcBoKHRgIBCIQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Fclass.reflectionclass.php&usg=AFQjCNEq1mkKTXyWLKBKMJmRyv65aQf5Nw) Class

```
 $reflect=new \ReflectionClass($leadgen_forms);
 $properties=$reflect->getProperties('content');
```

and [PtcHandyMan](http://phptoolcase.com/guides/ptc-hm-guide.html)

```
require_once('PtcHm.php');
 PtcHandyMan::register();
 $data = PtcHandyMan::getProperty( $leadgen_forms , 'content' );
```

but I am not able to access the protected property. Is there any way to access the protected property. And also I don't get why facebook is giving the protected response.

This is my whole function

```
  function get_page_forms(){
        if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            exit('No direct script access allowed');
        }
        $page_id = $_POST['page_id'];
        $page_access_token = $_POST['page_access_token'];
        Api::init('APPID', 'SECRET KEY', $page_access_token);
        $page = new Page($page_id);
        $leadgen_forms = $page->getLeadgenForms();
        //$reflect=new \ReflectionClass($leadgen_forms);
        //$properties=$reflect->getProperties('content');
        require_once('PtcHm.php');
        PtcHandyMan::register();
        $data = PtcHandyMan::getProperty( $leadgen_forms , 'content' );
        $allFormsArr = $data['data'];           
        $count = count($allFormsArr);
        $output = '<div class="container">
                    <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Id</td>
                                <td>Name</td>
                                <td>Leads csv file</td>
                                <td>Status</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>';
            for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
                $output .= '<tr>
                                <td>'.$allFormsArr[$i]['id'].'</td>
                                <td>'.$allFormsArr[$i]['name'].'</td>
                                <td><a href="'.$allFormsArr[$i]['leadgen_export_csv_url'].'" target="_new">Link</a></td>
                                <td>'.$allFormsArr[$i]['status'].'</td>
                            </tr>';
            }
           $output .= '</tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>';
        echo $output;
    }
```

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/forms-questions/v2.8#readingforms you should get a simple data structure back. And why does it say `FacebookAds\Object\Page` – are you sure that’s the method return value, and not just `$page` what you dumped there …?

Comment: Ignore `FacebookAds\Object\Page`.... My point is how to access the protected data. In documentation it shows simple data but its not simple it is protected as I have shown in the question.

Comment: What does `var_dump($leadgen_forms);` give as a result?

Comment: `var_dump($leadgen_forms);` is showing the same protected response. The main problem is, that I am getting the response but I am not able to access that specific data from that response because its protected.

Comment: When I try to access `var_dump($leadgen_form->content)`. Its giving me null.

Comment: Don’t those objects have methods like toArray or something like that?

Comment: I dont think so..

Comment: @CBroe You are right. There is a method like toArray. Something like that at least. It's asArray.

Comment: @MuhammadSajjad Have you tried a simple foreach? I mean without Reflection Class and extra classes. Have you tried asArray method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot ways to access the responses from facebook API.

Your code:

```
$page = new Page($page_id);
$leadgen_forms = $page->getLeadgenForms();
```

you are getting the response like this :

```
FacebookAds\Object\Page
  (
    [response:protected] => FacebookAds\Http\Response Object
       (
        [response:protected] => Array
          (
            [data] => Array
              (MY DATA)
          )
      )
  )
```

You can use asArray method

```
$page = new Page($page_id);
$leadgen_forms = $page->getLeadgenForms()->asArray();
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphNode/5.0.0

or if you don't want to use asArray use simple foreach for deeper levels:

```
foreach ($leadgen_forms as $leadgen_form) {
  heres your array. It may be protected so you might want to dig deeper with another foreach and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using getter methods for the property like `getContent`. This might get you access to the protected property.